# How to correct the wrong result of the cut method?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get five intervals of 150 samples but apparently the R cut method is giving me a wrong result. Below I leave the dataset and the code

```r
age = c(89,81,59,80,74,36,28,73,44,51,31,75,31,60,42,16,38,76,72,67,47,31,63,45,58,78,45,90,41,53,24,47,41,24,59,
18,72,12,79,80,73,47,74,37,30,24,61,50,82,84,63,60,39,23,72,67,46,37,14,90,50,12,20,25,55,87,59,76,23,23,
36,61,19,65,42,80,23,41,20,77,20,52,54,33,38,53,71,78,71,12,77,40,80,23,45,58,73,24,50,15,81,61,59,33,37,
51,59,25,17,65,83,35,78,48,25,38,88,14,40,72,80,89,70,42,88,14,51,35,21,88,73,53,81,85,30,66,57,34,90,53,
40,80,76,24,33,69,81,52,35,33)

table((cut(age, breaks=5, right=FALSE, dig.lab=2))

# ---- results (wrong) ----
[12,28) [28,43) [43,59) [59,74) [74,90) 
     28      32      26      31      33
```

the correct result is as shown in the following table

| [12 - 28> | [28 - 43> | [43 - 59> | [59 - 74> | [74 - 90] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 32 | 26 | 29 | 35 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choice of `dig.lab` just affects the labels for the levels, not the actual values for the the cuts. If you run

```
levels(cut(age, breaks=5, right=FALSE))
# [1] "[11.9,27.6)" "[27.6,43.2)" "[43.2,58.8)" "[58.8,74.4)"
# [5] "[74.4,90.1)"
```

You'll see that the actual breaks have decimal points. Those same breaks are used even when you change the labels with `dig.lab`. The `dig.lab` option is purely cosmetic.

If you want to use those exact breaks, you'll need to specify them yourself. For example

```
table(cut(age, breaks=c(12,38,43,59,74,90), right=FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE))
# [12,38) [38,43) [43,59) [59,74) [74,90] 
#      47      13      26      29      35
```

Comment: interesting, I had that intuition of better defining them manually. Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (but only if you don't want those exact bins) for getting an equal number of observations with no decimal points is to use the `ggplot2::cut_number()` function. In your case, you could use:

```
library(ggplot2)
table(ggplot2::cut_number(age,5, right=FALSE, dig.lab=2))
#[12,30) [30,43) [43,59) [59,76) [76,90] 
#    29      31      26      32      32
```

Comment: interesting, tank you @Andy